# Configure our Entity framework classes to connect to our staging database server

Tags: deployment, entity-framework-4

I have entity framework data access to connect to two sql server 2008 databases inside our development environment. Currently I need to move our asp.net mvc web application from our dev environment to our staging environment. so my question is how I can configure my existing entity framework to connect to our staging server?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this is a web project, your connections to the SQL Server databases are likely defined in **web.config**. If a Windows application, then **app.config**. You would need to look in those places to adjust the addresses.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityFramework.ProjectName.csdl|res://*/EntityFramework.ProjectName.ssdl|res://*/EntityFramework.ProjectName.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=[QUALIFIEDSERVERNAME];integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I would suggest using transformation files to control their values between environments.